# Allocating One Instance per Thread (Boost Environment)

Tags: boost, thread-local

I'm new to Boost and I am redesigning a logging class that must work in a threaded application. It was designed to work like an ostream object but "did not work" (Said in Eddy Izzard voice for those of you who know of his reference to Davinci's helicopter).

You might use it as follows:

```
Logger &logger = Logger::instance();
logger << "He designed a helicopter you know...that did not work." << endl;
```

So it was originally designed as a singleton and after a few approaches I thought perhaps Logger::instance() could return a Logger unique to the thread. I might use the STL to define a map between a Boost Thread ID and an instance of the Logger class.

Then I started thinking that perhaps there might be a smarter way to do this using some form of thread-local storage?

One issue with the map is that I must do some house cleaning to periodically delete Loggers when threads have terminated. I began to feel like I was reinventing things.

I see that Boost supports thread-local storage.

Any thoughts or caveats?

Thanks,

Kenny

Answer (score 0):

I used the Boost thread-local storage and registered each logger with an object that funnels the data to either files or cout.

Kenny